# Exception Handling for college assignment

Tags: java

I'm doing an assignment for college at the moment on Exceptions. I've written some code but it's not working, just wondering if anyone can spot where I'm going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've written a class specifically to deal with a InputMismatchException, however, when I enter a double into the array rather than an integer, the programme still crashes rather than the exception being handled like I want it to.

Thanks.

```
public class Lab8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean x = true;
        while (x == true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter the next integer: ");
                /*Autoboxing takes place here. The primitive type "int" taken in from the
                user is converted to an Integer object.*/
                Integer i = s.nextInt();
                a.add(i);
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("You must enter an integer.");
            }

            System.out.println("Would you like to enter another integer? (Y/N): ");
            char y_n = s.next().charAt(0);
            if (y_n == 'Y') {
                x = true;
            } else {
                x = false;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(a.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the application is raising another exception that you aren't capturing, you could always use Exception instead of InputMisMatchException which will catch all exceptions.

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger, what is the exception thrown and what line throws it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
s = new Scanner(System.in);
```

like this

```
System.out.println("Would you like to enter another integer? (Y/N): ");
s = new Scanner(System.in);
char y_n = s.next().charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Scanner couldn't pull an int from the input, it's still stuck in there.  You need to clear the input before looking for something new; or else `next.charAt(0)` is going to be the first digit of the double (in your example). In your catch clause, add

```
s.next();
```